# I have this error: Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: reactjs, forms

i have the error in the title, i supposed that im making a lot of requests to my api but i dont understand why or where. Im still learning so i dont fully understand this error and this is my first post here.
This is the code:

```
"use client";
import Image from "next/image";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import Edit from "@/public/edit-white.svg";
import Save from "@/public/save-white.svg";
import Close from "@/public/close-circle-white.svg";
import React, { FormEvent, MouseEvent, useState } from "react";
import PutUserConfig from "./putUserConfig";
import { signIn } from "@/auth";

interface FormData {
  username: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

interface ButtonProps {
  onClick: (event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
}
const EditButton: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({ onClick }) => {
  return (
    <button
      type="reset"
      onClick={onClick}
      className="bg-trendy-pink-600 p-1 my-2 mx-2 rounded-xl shadow-xl"
    >
      <Image width={40} height={40} src={Edit} alt={"Edit"} />
    </button>
  );
};
const CloseButton: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({ onClick }) => {
  return (
    <button
      type="reset"
      onClick={onClick}
      className="bg-trendy-pink-600 p-1 my-2 mx-2 rounded-xl shadow-xl"
    >
      <Image width={40} height={40} src={Close} alt={"Close"} />
    </button>
  );
};
const SaveButton: React.FC = (/*{ onClick }*/) => {
  return (
    <button
      type="submit"
      //onClick={onClick}
      className="bg-trendy-pink-600 p-1 my-2 mx-2 rounded-xl shadow-xl"
    >
      <Image width={40} height={40} src={Save} alt="Save" />
    </button>
  );
};

export default function Config() {
  const session = useSession();

  const prefix: string | undefined = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PREFIX_CLOUDINARY;
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState<FormData>({
    username: session.data?.user.name as string,
    email: session.data?.user.email as string,
    password: session.data?.user.password as string,
  });
  const [inputsEnabled, setInputsEnabled] = useState(false);

  const handleInputChange = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
    key: keyof FormData
  ) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [key]: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleEditClick = async () => {
    await setInputsEnabled(true);
  };

  // const handleSaveClick = async () => {
  //   setInputsEnabled(false);
  // };

  const handleCancelClick = () => {
    setInputsEnabled(false);
  };

  const handleSubmitUser = async (e: FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("handle put");

    const responseData = await PutUserConfig(
      session.data?.user.id as string,
      formData.email,
      formData.username,
      formData.password
    );
    if (responseData) {
      console.log("responseData put ok");
      signIn(
        "credentials",
        { callbackUrl: "/admin" },
        {
          email: `${session.data?.user.email}`,
          password: `${session.data?.user.password}`,
        }
      );
    }
    setInputsEnabled(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="w-full h-screen flex sm:text-sm md:text-base lg:text-lg text-lg">
      <div className="w-3/12 h-full flex"></div>
      <div className="flex flex-col py-3 gap-3 h-full w-full items-center justify-center">
        <div className="flex w-full h-2/6 gap-3">
          <div className="bg-gray-200 flex flex-col shadow-gray-400 shadow-md w-full h-full p-3 gap-3 rounded-xl justify-center">
            <form
              method="post"
              onSubmit={handleSubmitUser}
              className="flex flex-col"
            >
              <div className="flex justify-between items-center">
                <h1 className="text-2xl text-revolver-600 font-bold">
                  Configuración de usuario
                </h1>
                <div>
                  {inputsEnabled ? (
                    <>
                      <SaveButton /*onClick={handleSaveClick}*/ />
                      <CloseButton onClick={handleCancelClick} />
                    </>
                  ) : (
                    <EditButton onClick={handleEditClick} />
                  )}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="flex flex-col gap-2">
                <div className="flex-row w-full gap-2">
                  <label className="font-bold">Correo:</label>
                  <input
                    required
                    pattern=".*@.*\.com"
                    readOnly={!inputsEnabled}
                    className="rounded-lg px-2"
                    type="text"
                    name="Email"
                    value={formData.email}
                    onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, "email")}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="flex flex-row gap-2">
                  <label className="font-bold">Nombre de usuario:</label>
                  <input
                    required
                    readOnly={!inputsEnabled}
                    placeholder={`${session.data?.user.name}`}
                    className="rounded-lg px-2"
                    type="text"
                    name="User"
                    value={formData.username}
                    onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, "username")}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="flex flex-row gap-2">
                  <label className="font-bold">Contraseña:</label>
                  <input
                    required
                    readOnly={!inputsEnabled}
                    placeholder="------------"
                    className="rounded-lg px-2"
                    type="password"
                    name="Password"
                    value={formData.password}
                    onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, "password")}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div
            className="bg-gray-200 flex flex-col shadow-gray-400 shadow-md w-1/4 h-full px-3 py-1 gap-2
           rounded-xl"
          >
            <div className="flex justify-between items-center">
              <h1 className="text-2xl text-revolver-600 font-bold">
                Foto de perfil
              </h1>
              <EditButton onClick={() => {}}></EditButton>
            </div>
            <div className="flex h-full w-full justify-center pb-1">
              <Image
                src={prefix! + session.data?.user.boutique?.logoUrl}
                width={100}
                height={100}
                alt="Logo"
                className="w-40 rounded-md"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="bg-gray-200 flex flex-col shadow-gray-400 shadow-md w-full h-2/6 p-3 gap-3 rounded-xl justify-center">
          <div className="flex justify-between items-center">
            <h1 className="text-2xl text-revolver-600 font-bold">
              Configuración de la Boutique
            </h1>
            <EditButton onClick={() => {}}></EditButton>
          </div>
          <p>
            Nombre de la boutique: {session.data?.user.boutique?.boutiqueName}
            {session.data?.user.boutique?.products[0].productId}
          </p>
          <p>Dirección: {session.data?.user.boutique?.address}</p>
          <p>
            Descripción de la boutique: {session.data?.user.boutique?.address}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="bg-gray-200 flex flex-col shadow-gray-400 shadow-md w-full h-2/6 p-3 gap-3 rounded-xl justify-center">
          <div className="flex justify-between items-center">
            <h1 className="text-2xl text-revolver-600 font-bold">
              Configuración de pago
            </h1>
            <EditButton onClick={() => {}}></EditButton>
          </div>
          <p>
            Tipo suscripcion:{" "}
            {session.data?.user.boutique?.billingInfo[0].timeSubscription}
          </p>
          <p>
            Monto de pago: {session.data?.user.boutique?.billingInfo[0].amount}
          </p>
          <p>
            Ultimo dia de pago:{" "}
            {session.data?.user.boutique?.billingInfo[0].lastPayDay.toString()}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="w-3/12 h-full flex"></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

i have ask to chatgpt and copilot but they keep saying that my code is fine.

Comment: Remember that if you run into an error, [show that error in your post](/help/how-to-ask) (exactly the way it's printed, with the stack trace, etc)

Comment: whenever i had that error it was connected to a useEffect in either the same component or the parent.